# failed for URL: "message://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme message"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to open the email app (from emulator) and send an email from there but when i click the button i'm getting this error below but the app is not crashing

**The error:**

```
iGrow Goals[41098:3002008] -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "message://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme message"
```

**My function:**

```
func sendEmail() {

    //  Converted to Swift 5.4 by Swiftify v5.4.24488
    let mailURL = URL(string: "message://")
    if let mailURL = mailURL {
        if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(mailURL) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(mailURL, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try in real device. simulator won't support email. Also check here to send email. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-send-an-email

Comment: @FahimParkar i don't have a real device

Comment: If you want the user to return to your app once the email is sent, use `MFMailComposeViewController` (as suggested by Fahim).

Comment: Your code should work fine on a real device. When you call `sendEmail`, the Mail app will be opened (note: a user may not have the Mail app). Since Simulator doesn't have the Mail app, you are not able to do that on the Simulator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not work in the simulator, only on a real device.

Don't forget to configure your Info.plist and add entry to message under this key: **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes**, so you can query it with canOpenURL.

Example Info.plist file that whitelists the URl query schemes :

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>googlegmail</string>
  <string>mailto</string>
  <string>instagram</string>
  <string>message</string>
</array>
```

[image: Info.plist]

You can also consider to use the mailto schema

```
let mailURL = URL(string: "mailto://example@example.com")
```

Comment: I will try this, but i don't have a real device and i don't want to buy one to test this one simple feature

Answer (score 0):

To set the value for the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key in XCode when editing Info.plist, use "**Queried URL Schemes**":
[image: Info.plist screenshot from XCode]

When editing the Info.plist manually, use the **LSApplicationQueriesSchemes** key as [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3177963/alexander-g) pointed out above:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>message</string>
</array>
```